# Lastpass login settings

Tags: lastpass

Lastpass never prompts me for the master password. How do I change this? Ideally I want to be prompted once when I log into my computer, even if I close and reopen the web browser.

Also, I don't understand the settings "Website auto-logoff timeout" and "Website auto-logoff timeout". Is the idea that Lastpass automatically logs you out of a site after the time has past? How does this make any sense because if Lastpass was enabled then it would just log the user back in again?

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the LastPass icon in your browser;
2. Click on Preferences;
3. In the small window on your left, click on *Account Settings*;
4. Click on *Click here to launch Account Settings*; a new window will open;
5. In the *Edit Settings* window that opens, choose *Security*;
6. Midway through the window that opens, you will read: *Prompt for LastPass Master Password when:*. You will be offered several choices, make yours.

Answer (score 0):

Logoff from LastPass. When logging, unselect "Remember email" and "Remember password". You'll be prompted for master password when logging in.

Website auto logoff after idle & Website auto logoff after all browsers are closed timeout determine after how many minutes LastPass should log out from LastPass vault if you you are idle & if you close all browsers, respectively